# Pandas: How to correct time data in pandas data frame to then combine with date column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, timedelta

I have a date and time column in my data, but my time column has times over 24 therefore, in order to use it for analysis, I need to correct it, so I can do some analysis, for those cases I have to subtract 24

My data is like this:

```
    Date       Start Time     
0  2021-10-01  06:31:00   
1  2021-10-15  10:21:09   
2  2021-10-01  29:00:33  
3  2021-10-31  24:02:45   
4  2021-11-01  25:00:12
```

My attempt was to create the following function:

```
def fix_24(time):
    hour_re = re.compile('^(\d+):')
    hour = int(re.search(hour_re,time).group(1))
    hour_minus_24 = str(hour-24)
    return re.sub(hour_re,f'{hour_minus_24}:',time) if hour>=24  else time
```

This corrects the time but it adds the current date

```
df_red['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_red['Start time'].apply(fix_24))
2022-03-08 06:09:52
```

And if I use timedelta, it adds "0 days"

```
df_red['timedelta'] = pd.to_timedelta(df_red['Start time'].apply(fix_24).str[-8:])
0 days 06:09:52
```

So, now my attemps look like these:

```
    Date       Start Time     timedelta       datetime               Should be
0  2021-10-01  06:31:00   0 days 06:31:00     2022-03-08 06:31:00    06:31:00
1  2021-10-15  10:21:09   0 days 10:21:09     2022-03-08 10:21:09    10:21:09
2  2021-10-01  29:00:33   0 days 05:00:33     2022-03-08 05:00:33    05:00:33
3  2021-10-31  24:02:45   0 days 00:02:45     2022-03-08 00:02:45    00:02:45
4  2021-11-01  25:00:12   0 days 01:00:12     2022-03-08 01:00:12    01:00:12
```

And I also tried to combine the timedelta I created and the Date column but I get an error:

```
df_red.Date=pd.to_datetime(df_red.Date) 
df_red.timedelta=pd.to_timedelta(df_red.timedelta) 


pd.to_datetime(df_red.Date + ' ' + df_red.timedelta)


TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeArray' and 'str'
```

but basically I would like to have the corrected date and time, so I can create my timestamp column.

Answer (score 0):

This function has solved my issue:

```
def change_time(df,date_col, time_col):
    #Function to fix the shifted time
    df['Changed time'] = pd.to_timedelta(time_col)
    df['Changed time'] = df['Changed time'] - pd.to_timedelta(df['Changed time'].dt.days, unit='d')
    date_col = pd.to_datetime(date_col)
    df['Datetime'] = date_col + df['Changed time']
    return df
```